# Formatting data in a CSV file (calculating average) in python

Tags: csv, python-3.x

```
import csv
with open('Class1scores.csv') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line.split() 
        if len(parts) > 1:   
            print (parts[4])   


f = open('Class1scores.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
newlist = []
for row in csv_f:

    row[1] = int(row[1])
    row[2] = int(row[2])
    row[3] = int(row[3])

    maximum = max(row[1:3])
    row.append(maximum)
    average = round(sum(row[1:3])/3)
    row.append(average)
    newlist.append(row[0:4])

averageScore = [[x[3], x[0]] for x in newlist]
print('\nStudents Average Scores From Highest to Lowest\n')
```

Here the code is meant to read the CSV file and in the first three rows (row 0 being the users name) it should add all the three scores and divide by three but it doesn't calculate a proper average, it just takes the score from the last column.

[image: csv file]

Comment: Could you post first few lines of your CSV file.

Comment: what's the point of opening the file twice?

Comment: Billy, check out my answer below. You can cut out parts you don't need and implement it for your own needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want statistics of each row. In general you should do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rows:
        name = row[0]
        scores = row[1:]

        # calculate statistics of scores
        attributes = {
           'NAME': name,
           'MAX' : max(scores),
           'MIN' : min(scores),
           'AVE' : 1.0 * sum(scores) / len(scores)
        }

        output_mesg ="name: {NAME:s} \t high: {MAX:d} \t low: {MIN:d} \t ave: {AVE:f}"
        print(output_mesg.format(**attributes))
```

Try not to consider if doing specific things is inefficient locally. A good `Pythonic` script should be as readable as possible to every one.

In your code, I spot two mistakes:

1. Appending to `row` won't change anything, since row is a local variable in for loop and will get garbage collected.
2. `row[1:3]` only gives the second and the third element. `row[1:4]` gives what you want, as well as `row[1:]`. Indexing in `Python` normally is end-exclusive.

And some questions for you to think about:

> If I can open the file in `Excel` and it's not that big, why not just do it in `Excel`? Can I make use of all the tools I have to get work done as soon as possible with least effort? Can I get done with this task in 30 seconds?

Comment: your code contains an error as it doesn't output anything. Doesn't the print line need brackets as it's python 3?

Comment: @Billy I looked up `Python3` print examples at https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/inputoutput.html, and added a bracket and a format function call. Hope it's right.

Comment: Because I'm new to Python, I'm curious as to why you are multiplying sum(scores) / len(scores) by 1.0. Is it to prevent integer data types being used?

Comment: @MartinBrown you are right. `1.0` there is to prevent `integer division`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. See both parts. First, we create a dictionary with names as the key and a list of results as values.

```
import csv


fileLineList = []
averageScoreDict = {}

with open('Class1scores.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        fileLineList.append(row)

for row in fileLineList:
    highest = 0
    lowest = 0
    total = 0
    average = 0
    for column in row:
        if column.isdigit():
            column = int(column)
            if column > highest:
                highest = column
            if column < lowest or lowest == 0:
                lowest = column
            total += column    
    average = total / 3
    averageScoreDict[row[0]] = [highest, lowest, round(average)]

print(averageScoreDict)
```

Output:

`{'Milky': [7, 4, 5], 'Billy': [6, 5, 6], 'Adam': [5, 2, 4], 'John': [10, 7, 9]}`

Now that we have our dictionary, we can create your desired final output by sorting the list. See this updated code:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter


fileLineList = []
averageScoreDict = {} # Creating an empty dictionary here.

with open('Class1scores.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        fileLineList.append(row)

for row in fileLineList:
    highest = 0
    lowest = 0
    total = 0
    average = 0
    for column in row:
        if column.isdigit():
            column = int(column)
            if column > highest:
                highest = column
            if column < lowest or lowest == 0:
                lowest = column
            total += column    
    average = total / 3
    # Here is where we put the emtpy dictinary created earlier to good use.
    # We assign the key, in this case the contents of the first column of
    # the CSV, to the list of values. 
    # For the first line of the file, the Key would be 'John'.
    # We are assigning a list to John which is 3 integers: 
    #   highest, lowest and average (which is a float we round)
    averageScoreDict[row[0]] = [highest, lowest, round(average)]

averageScoreList = []

# Here we "unpack" the dictionary we have created and create a list of Keys.
# which are the names and single value we want, in this case the average.
for key, value in averageScoreDict.items():
    averageScoreList.append([key, value[2]])

# Sorting the list using the value instead of the name.
averageScoreList.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)    

print('\nStudents Average Scores From Highest to Lowest\n')
print(averageScoreList)
```

Output:

`Students Average Scores From Highest to Lowest
[['John', 9], ['Billy', 6], ['Milky', 5], ['Adam', 4]]`

Comment: can you comment each line so i have a better understanding of the dictionary concept?

Comment: I will do you one better, read about it here. I think he does a great job explaining the concept. [Hands-on Python Tutorial > 1.12. Dictionaries](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/dictionaries.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Also, in their any way of printint the data line by line as it's stored in an array because you can't just use "\n".

Comment: Last thing, how do you know what to define your key to in a dictionary? and why do you need reverse to be set to true?

Comment: I added some comments to the code example as well. It is kind of convoluted way to go about it, but it is good learning. In python we generally refer to arrays as lists. The simplest way to print contents of a list is a for loop. For example: ``for i in averageScoreList:`` next line ``print(i)``. You can also import pprint and pprint your dictionaries and list, sometimes this makes it easier to see the data structure. For example ``pprint.pprint(averageScoreList)``

Comment: I set the reverse sorting to true so the list is ordered from highest to lowest value. If we don't set that boolean to true, it will sort from lowest to highest. Don't be afraid to modify code and play round with the results. I prefer to just make as simple case as possible and learn on that. It can be easier to understand without a bunch of existing code.

Comment: I use the name as my dictionary key because in the future we can just say something like ``print(averageScoreDict['John'])`` and it will give us all the values we associated with that key. In this case a list of 3 integers. It is just a way to structure our data for easy reference later in our code.