# How to find an average from a specific row of a csv file by using loops in python?

Tags: python

```
f = open('TB_burden_countries_2014-09-29.csv')
for row in csv.reader(f):
    print(row[7])
```

This basically reads the file and prints out the specific row, now how do I find the average of that very row by using loops. Thank you

Comment: share a subset of csv and explain what you are looking for and what is the problem you are facing

Comment: may this helps: https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Comment: I think you're confusing rows and columns. This prints a specific column of every row.

Comment: @Barmar print a specific column of every row ?

Comment: Add the column to a total variable, and increment a counter. At the end, divide the total by the counter to get the average. This is high school math.

Comment: A for loop is also not the advised way to interact with a pandas df. You can just get row or column-wise means by using built in pandas functions.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google look up I found this post by "Billy".

[Formatting data in a CSV file (calculating average) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990023/formatting-data-in-a-csv-file-calculating-average-in-python)

Basically you want statistics of each row. In general you should do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rows:
        name = row[0]
        scores = row[1:]

    # calculate statistics of scores
    attributes = {
       'NAME': name,
       'MAX' : max(scores),
       'MIN' : min(scores),
       'AVE' : 1.0 * sum(scores) / len(scores)
    }

    output_mesg ="name: {NAME:s} \t high: {MAX:d} \t low: {MIN:d} \t ave: {AVE:f}"
    print(output_mesg.format(**attributes))
```

Try not to consider if doing specific things is inefficient locally. A good Pythonic script should be as readable as possible to every one.

In your code, I spot two mistakes:

1. Appending to row won't change anything, since row is a local variable in for loop and will get garbage collected.
2. row[1:3] only gives the second and the third element. row[1:4] gives what you want, as well as row[1:]. Indexing in Python normally is end-exclusive.

And some questions for you to think about:

> If I can open the file in Excel and it's not that big, why not just do it in Excel? Can I make use of all the tools I have to get work done as soon as possible with least effort? Can I get done with this task in 30 seconds?